# Jitsi Meet make command not working on Windows

Tags: reactjs, makefile, gnu-make, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I cloned Jitsi Meet repo on Windows but when I try to build with **make** command it fails (That I installed from  [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)). I tried on ubuntu and it worked so that's strictly a Windows issue.

This is the error when I tried to build.

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

It seems that windows **make** not recognize the relative path of linux **make**, so I replaced all the . with a absolute path to the local repo and after it builds some files it stops here.

```
rm -fr libs
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -fr libs, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [deploy-init] Error 2
```

What else should I change to make the build work?

```
BUILD_DIR = build
CLEANCSS = ./node_modules/.bin/cleancss
DEPLOY_DIR = libs
LIBJITSIMEET_DIR = node_modules/lib-jitsi-meet/
LIBFLAC_DIR = node_modules/libflacjs/dist/min/
OLM_DIR = node_modules/olm
RNNOISE_WASM_DIR = node_modules/rnnoise-wasm/dist/
NODE_SASS = ./node_modules/.bin/sass
NPM = npm
OUTPUT_DIR = .
STYLES_BUNDLE = css/all.bundle.css
STYLES_DESTINATION = css/all.css
STYLES_MAIN = css/main.scss
WEBPACK = ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER = ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server

all: compile deploy clean

compile:
    $(WEBPACK) -p

clean:
    rm -fr $(BUILD_DIR)

.NOTPARALLEL:
deploy: deploy-init deploy-appbundle deploy-rnnoise-binary deploy-lib-jitsi-meet deploy-libflac 
deploy-olm deploy-css deploy-local

deploy-init:
    rm -fr $(DEPLOY_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(DEPLOY_DIR)

deploy-appbundle:
    cp \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/app.bundle.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/app.bundle.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/do_external_connect.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/do_external_connect.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/external_api.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/external_api.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/flacEncodeWorker.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/flacEncodeWorker.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/device_selection_popup_bundle.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/device_selection_popup_bundle.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/dial_in_info_bundle.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/dial_in_info_bundle.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/alwaysontop.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/alwaysontop.min.map \
        $(OUTPUT_DIR)/analytics-ga.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/analytics-ga.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/analytics-ga.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/video-blur-effect.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/video-blur-effect.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/rnnoise-processor.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/rnnoise-processor.min.map \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/close3.min.js \
        $(BUILD_DIR)/close3.min.map \
        $(DEPLOY_DIR)

deploy-lib-jitsi-meet:
    cp \
        $(LIBJITSIMEET_DIR)/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js \
        $(LIBJITSIMEET_DIR)/lib-jitsi-meet.min.map \
        $(LIBJITSIMEET_DIR)/lib-jitsi-meet.e2ee-worker.js \
        $(LIBJITSIMEET_DIR)/connection_optimization/external_connect.js \
        $(LIBJITSIMEET_DIR)/modules/browser/capabilities.json \
        $(DEPLOY_DIR)

deploy-libflac:
    cp \
        $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/libflac4-1.3.2.min.js \
        $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/libflac4-1.3.2.min.js.mem \
        $(DEPLOY_DIR)

deploy-olm:
    cp \
        $(OLM_DIR)/olm.wasm \
        $(DEPLOY_DIR)

deploy-rnnoise-binary:
    cp \
        $(RNNOISE_WASM_DIR)/rnnoise.wasm \
        $(DEPLOY_DIR)

deploy-css:
    $(NODE_SASS) $(STYLES_MAIN) $(STYLES_BUNDLE) && \
    $(CLEANCSS) --skip-rebase $(STYLES_BUNDLE) > $(STYLES_DESTINATION) ; \
    rm $(STYLES_BUNDLE)

deploy-local:
    ([ ! -x deploy-local.sh ] || ./deploy-local.sh)

.NOTPARALLEL:
dev: deploy-init deploy-css deploy-rnnoise-binary deploy-lib-jitsi-meet deploy-libflac deploy-olm
    $(WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER) --detect-circular-deps

source-package:
    mkdir -p source_package/jitsi-meet/css && \
    cp -r *.js *.html resources/*.txt connection_optimization favicon.ico fonts images libs static 
sounds LICENSE lang source_package/jitsi-meet && \
    cp css/all.css source_package/jitsi-meet/css && \
    (cd source_package ; tar cjf ../jitsi-meet.tar.bz2 jitsi-meet) && \
    rm -rf source_package
```

Comment: All of this Makefile is written with Unix in mind, so you won't be able to run it under Windows directly without major changes. You would either run it under WSL or install some POSIX emulation environment like Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: Yea, I also tried with WSL but Intellij does not index files so it makes development to hard, so I guess it only remain to run an emulation environment